# How can I enable British English with Oxford spelling in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, language

Although Google products offer a British English language option, they don't support Oxford spelling (-ize suffixes, among other things). In fact, it's fairly uncommon for any software to offer Oxford spelling.

How can I enable it in Google Chrome?

Comment: Question was already closed once as off-topic : https://superuser.com/questions/1373419/how-can-i-enable-british-english-with-oxford-spelling-in-google-products

Comment: This is a different question. That question was closed because apparently Android is off topic (despite there being multiple Android related tags), this relates specifically to Google Chrome (which also has a tag, FWIW). There are many other questions here about Chrome.

Comment: "it's fairly uncommon for any software to offer Oxford spelling." That's because nobody uses it ...

Comment: @DavidPostill except me and most of British academia etc. Thanks for the helpful comment though.

Comment: There is a large list of words at [English (British) spellings not recognized by the spell checker - Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OerhBusTovM;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQdrF46Tl9geDIzdDO3JLGfDHcUpA596qNqU1WtJCWnwbPK22tyGiQCwNghZxYnKLrfNYIXU%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) that you can add to the spelling dictionary ...

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** You can now choose "English (United Kingdom, Oxford English Dictionary spelling)" as the locale/spell checker in Chrome's settings.

---

It doesn't exist yet, but I'm trying to add this as a separate locale into Google Chrome. Keep your eyes peeled.

In the meantime, you can effectively get the same functionality (assuming spell checking is what you're after and not the browser interface being in Oxford spelling) by replacing the "English (United Kingdom)" (en-GB) dictionary that your installation of Chrome uses with [the one I've recently compiled](https://ufile.io/pgmgjva5) that uses Oxford spelling (en-GB-oxendict) exclusively.

The file would be named `en-GB-*-0.bdic` where `*` is a version number (e.g., `8` for the latest version as of this writing) in one of the following locations based on your OS:

**Windows:**

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

**Mac (not 100% sure here, you'll need to look around):**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Dictionaries
```

**Linux:**

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Dictionaries
```

The copied file needs to have the same file name as the file you replaced. Once that's done, just restart your browser and you'll have Chrome using Oxford spelling for its spellchecker.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to "enable" an additional dictionary with these words or bulk add words in Chrome (or just about any modern browser). You can, however, manually add words to the dictionary.

**Method 1: Adding words manually in Settings**

In Google Chrome open Settings > Advanced, and scroll down to and expand Language.

Under Spell Check click Custom Spelling and you can paste words in, one at a time.

**Method 2: Adding words manually in a text box**

Go to a website that contains a text box you can type in.

Find a list of words you wish to add, copy these, and paste them into the text box.

Right-click on each word in turn and choose to add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is strictly Oxford English, but there is a way to get British English spell checking...

In **Settings** > **Language** add 'English (United Kingdom)`:

[image: Adding English (United Kingdom) to Google Chrome's list of Languages]

Then 'English (United Kingdom)' is available in the **Spell check** section and can be enabled:

[image: Setting Google Chrome's Spell Checking to English (United Kingdom)]

Comment: OED English is roughly a subset of British English. Where British English allows both "organize" and "organise", OED English only accepts the former. OED English is favoured by many international organizations such as the UN.